# How to write this Ruby function using a loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a more elegant way to write this in Ruby, maybe using a loop?

```
def save_related_info
  update_column(:sender_company_name, user.preference.company_name)
  update_column(:sender_address, user.preference.address)
  update_column(:sender_telephone, user.preference.telephone)
  update_column(:sender_email, user.preference.email)
  update_column(:sender_url, user.preference.url)
  update_column(:sender_vat_number, user.preference.vat_number)
  update_column(:sender_payment_details, user.preference.payment_details)
end
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: We don't have enough code, but it looks like that model should have an association to "preference" to avoid such duplication of data, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def save_related_info
  %w[company_name address telephone email url vat_number payment_details]
  .each{|s| update_column("sender_#{s}".to_sym, user.preference.send(s))}
end
```

Comment: maybe shorter with `:"sender_#{s}"`? and definitely I'd use the standard indented do/end block, more clear just at the expense of 1 line.

Comment: @tokland Regarding the symbol literal, it's the same. Putting a method and its block together in one line makes it look easier, I think.

Comment: Don't think that build column name from property name it's a good idea. In that example it could be correct but in general could cause a lot of problems and possible errors.

Comment: @silent_coder why? that seems like the DRY way of doing it, and from the question is clear there is a 1:1 correspondence, I don't see the problem. If some attribute changes then you create a hash with the exceptions, it's very typical stuff.

Comment: Ok, what if your column name it's a little bit different from property name. You will be providing regexp to build it correct? Or you will need to write additional function for that case, because that function couldn't to that.

Comment: If columns and properties did not match then I'd write a `column => property` hash. But if they all match I won't lose a second with it. Write the simplest code that works, update only when necessary.

Comment: But in that case you will need two function, and normally twice more tests for it. So you choose to save a line of code first, and then need to write new fuction, and tests for it. It's irrational. But after, during maintenanca developer will think, why there 2 almost the same functions? Too many possible problems to save just a line of code.

Answer (score 3):

Any reason you're not using `update_attributes` to do them all at once?

```
def save_related_info
  update_attributes(
    :sender_company_name => user.preference.company_name,
    :sender_address => user.preference.address,
    :sender_telephone => user.preference.telephone,
    :sender_email => user.preference.email,
    :sender_url => user.preference.url,
    :sender_vat_number => user.preference.vat_number,
    :sender_payment_details => user.preference.payment_details
  )
end
```

Comment: Note that `update_column` skips validations, callbacks and timestamps updating, so it's not the same.

Comment: @tokland That sounds like a bad idea to me, but if the OP does infact want to skip that stuff, Rails 4 has [update_columns](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_columns)

Comment: I agree, updating with pure SQL ignoring all the model stuff is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Good point. I am still learning Ruby, so I just read up on the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

first guess is to put keys in and values in lists and then use loop. something like this:

```
keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']
values = [val1, val2, val3, val4]
keys.each_index do |i|
 update_column(keys[i], values[i])
end
```

Minus in that approach is that the order of elements in `values` array should fit for order of keys. You could avoid it of using hash instead of arrays. Code will looks like this:

```
data = { "key1" => val1, "key2" => val2, "key3" => val3 };
data.each do |key, value|
 update_column(keys, values)
end
```

Comment: note that you'd use `zip` in the first snippet if you decided to write it this way.

Comment: I know that it will be better from ruby style point of view, but I'm coding multiple languages and I prefer to have solid coding style which is the same for most of the languages. But I'm agree, that in Ruby case your better will be used %w notation.

Comment: Ok, but personally I prefer to write the most idiomatic code in every language (btw, a lot of languages have `zip`: haskell, python, scala, erlang, JS+underscore...).

Comment: @Ph0en1x If you keep the same style of coding for different languages, then that defeats the purpose of having different languages. Why do you think there are different languages?

Comment: Because clients need different languages. And in many cases I can't choose, just use what they ask.

Comment: `update_column(keys[i], values[i])` in the last example should be `update_column(key, value)`. What is `var` by the way?